# DocuSign required fields and a signature

Tags: templates, docusignapi

I am working on a PDF in the DocuSign console.  I'm working on setting it up as a template to be used by a system calling it using the API.  However, I'm having some issues.

When a user goes in to sign their document, they can click on the yellow "Next" on the left of the document and it goes straight to the signature block.  If they sign it, the system is not requiring any of the required fields to be filled in.  I have more than 20 required fields (setting up a demo) and two separate signers and neither of them have to sign any of the required fields prior to signing and completing the document.

I'm sure that there's something that I'm doing/not doing but I'll be darned if I see it.

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this definitely isn't an API-related question, but I'll take a crack at answering it nonetheless.

When editing the Template via the DocuSign web UI, the border color surrounding the field serves as a visual indicator regarding whether each field is designated as Required or Optional:

- If the border color for a field is **RED**, the field will be **Required** when the assigned recipient completes the form.
- If the border color for a field is **GREY**, the field will be **Optional** when the assigned recipient completes the form.

To specify a field as **Required**, examine the Properties for the field in the template by selecting the field and clicking on the "settings wheel" that appears to the right of the field. If you want the field to be Required for the assigned recipient (i.e., require that the assigned recipient populate the field prior to being able to confirm signing and submit the envelope), make sure that the **Required** checkbox is selected within the **Formatting Properties** section of the tag properties window.  (*Note*: There's a second checkbox labeled "Required" at the very bottom of the tag properties window -- this can be confusing and is **NOT** the checkbox to select to make the field required for the recipient.) To make the field required for the assigned recipient, you want to check the **Required** checkbox that's located within the "Formatting Properties" section:

[image: Tag Properties window]

Comment: THAT WAS IT!  I looked and saw where your "Required" check box was.  I verified in the document and I was checking the one in the "Conditional Fields" section!  That's why mine wasn't red.  When I checked the other checkbox, it turned red!  Thanks SO much, Kim, for your help!!