# DocuSign Rest API - Making Certain PDF Fields Required

Tags: pdf, docusignapi, pdf-form

I am sending a document to DocuSign (via byte array) in a Composite Template with multiple signers. DocuSign is recognizing the fields and everything is working perfectly.

However, I need to be able make some of these PDF form fields required. Is there a way to accomplish this? Is there something I can add to the form field itself that DocuSign will recognize and make it required?

All of the fields that show up are optional...

Also, lets say there are 4 checkboxes, and I need one of them to be checked. Is there a way to edit the PDF form fields so that will DocuSign will enforce this?

I would need to be able to make fields required for some signers and not required for others.

I know there are ways to do this within the DocuSign Template Panel, (depicted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502940/docusign-required-fields-and-a-signature)) but I need my app to write various fields on the PDF before I send it to DocuSign. So going this "Template" route isn't an option.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- *I need to be able make some of these PDF form fields required.*

You can set the form field as required in your Pdf document. When Docusign transforms those form fields(transformPdfFields=true), the '***required***' property is inherited

- *Also, lets say there are 4 checkboxes, and I need one of them to be checked. Is there a way to edit the PDF form fields so that will DocuSign will enforce this?*

In your Pdf form, you can use the radio button group to accomplish this. Docusign will honor the radio button group after the document is uploaded.

- I would need to be able to make fields required for some signers and not required for others.

In Docusign, You can either make a field required for a single signer or all signers.

You can use the [updateTabs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeTabs/update/) api to set additional tab behavior  after the envelope is created.

Comment: Thanks for your help